# Attach excel file to Notes and attachments in Salesforce using c#

Tags: oauth2, c#

I am not able to attach excel(.xls) file in "notes and attachments" section in the specific record in Salesforce using c#. I am a beginner in salesforce. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code:

```
const string qry = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact";
var result = await forceClient.QueryAsync<Contact>(qry);
byte[] inbuff = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file");
dynamic attach = new ExpandoObject();
attach.Body = inbuff;
attach.Name = "Test5" + ".xls";
attach.IsPrivate = false;
var createResults = await forceClient.CreateAsync("Contact", attach);
```

I am getting this type of error:

> "No such column 'Body' on sobject of type Contact

Comment: `forceClient.CreateAsync("Attachment", attach);` use attachment instead of contact

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update this line

```
forceClient.CreateAsync("Attachment", attach);
```

use attachment instead of contact